# Need MySQL idiom for checking whether string contains any of a set of characters

Tags: mysql, string, function, idioms

I need to run the following MySQL query:

```
SELECT id, name FROM mytable 
WHERE NOT CONTAINS_ANY(name, ';.<>#$!');
```

except that there doesn't seem to be anything like CONTAINS_ANY (taking two string and checking whether the first string contains any character of those in the second string). What can I do instead? I would like to avoid

```
SELECT id, name FROM mytable 
WHERE name NOT LIKE '%;%' 
  AND name NOT LIKE '%.%' 
  AND etc. etc.
```

and similar ugliness.

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/regexp.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use regex:

```
SELECT id, name
FROM mytable 
WHERE name not rlike '[;.<>#$!]';
```